# Angular CLI (Angular2) and WebStorm: How can I create a route within WebStorm?

Tags: testing, angular, routes, webstorm, auto-generate

WebStorm (Version >= 2006.2.EAP) provides [Angular-CLI](https://cli.angular.io/) to create new Angular2 Projects out of the box.

The question now is: How can I create a new route (with all the necessary files: component, html-tpl, spec.ts, e2e.specs, etc..) on the fly within WebStorm? "Right-Click > Create a new route" does not exist. Can someone help me further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebStorm provides no support for `ng generate`. If you miss it, please feel free to create a feature request in [youtrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB).
for now I can only suggest using built-in terminal to run `ng generate route <route/to/route-component>`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the Angular plugin (it is called AngularJS even though it supports Angular2.)

In the File / New / AngularCLI menu you can choose "route" to create a new route.
You can also assign a shortcut key to open the plugin's Angular CLI dialog.